# get the URL requested by the Angular $resource service

Tags: angularjs

I use the Angular `$resource` service to make HTTP calls such as

```
var reportEndpoint = $resource('http://example.org/:id');

reportEndpoint.get({id: 6}, function (response, responseHeaders) {
    $scope.report = response.data;
    // can I get here the URL that the request was submitted to
});
```

at the point indicated by the comment, is there some way to get the URL that the request was submitted to, which in the example above would be http://example.org/6

Comment: Why are you wanting the URL of the request at that point?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I just don't see why there would be business logic based off of the URL instead of properties on objects.

Comment: Any reason you can't just do `var reportUrl = 'http://example.org/:id, reportEndpoint = $resource(reportUrl);`?

Comment: @jperezov because I need `:id` to be replaced with the appropriate parameter value

Answer (score 3):

You can add an interceptor to your GET request, and attach the url to the response data. For example, you could do the following:

```
var reportEndpoint = $resource('http://example.org/:id', {}, {
  get: {
    method: 'GET',
    interceptor: {
      response: function (response) {
        response.data.responseUrl = response.config.url;
        return response.data;
      }
});

reportEndpoint.get({id: 6}, function (response) {
  $scope.report = response;

  // returns http://example.org/6
  console.log($scope.report.responseUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any direct way of retrieving the url from looking at the docs of $resource. An alternative but not optimal way to do it is by using the [$httpParamSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) to encode the data again and append that to the url to recreate the one that was used when sending the request.